# About Community when receiving trap with pysnmp

Tags: python-3.x, pysnmp

I'm currently trying to receive traps using pysnmp.
Let's assume that the original community name is exam.
At that time, when VRF was enabled on a certain device, the trap community name changed to something like xxx@exam, and pysnmp was unable to receive it properly.
Is there a way to specify community in a format like .*exam?

```
config.addTransport(snmp Engine,udp.domainName + (1,),udp.UdpTransport().openServerMode(('0.0.0.0', 162)))
config.addV1System(snmpEngine, 'my-area', 'exam')
```

I tried typing .*exam in the exam section, but it didn't work.

Comment: Sounds like a good feature request. You might want to raise it on https://github.com/lextudio/pysnmp/issues